# call subroutine yacc compiler

Tags: c, bison, yacc, lex

I'm developing a program complier using Lex and Yacc. The main target for this complier is to deal with multilayered external sub-routine calls while avoiding any kind of recursive function calls. My logic to achieve this is as follow:

I will first scan the main program. For all sub-function calls in that program I found, I would then jump into that sub-function do another scanning for the subsequent function calls. This process would be repeated until the end is reached or a predefined maximum stack number is reached. However, there’s no detection for any recursive function calls.

Because I have limited information about yacc, is this the correct way to use yacc to deal with sub-function calls? Also, does anyone have any suggestion on how to detect recursive function calls using yacc.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just scan the program twice?  The first time to build a list of declared (or defined) functions and add each to a table of these nodes. The second time to scan each function to see what functions they in turn call and build a tree.  Then use a common graph traversal algorithm to find loops.

Comment: 'Jump into that subroutine' sound wrong — how would you find where it is?  You need to do some rethinking.  You probably need to read all the material, and analyze it as you go, rather than trying to be selective.  You'd end up rescanning stuff, which is harder work than scanning once, saving as you go.  Recursion — direct recursion — is easy; you know which function you're scanning, so calls to that function inside the function are recursive.  Indirect recursion requires scanning of multiple functions.

Comment: Construct a graph and look for loops. Should be doable in a single pass on each function.

Comment: @selbie are two traversals really required? A new node can be created in the table every time a new function is encountered. Unless he is trying to parse C++ and it can have implicit constructor calls.

Comment: How are you going to deal with calls across the compilation units?

Comment: You seem to be conflating parsing with execution. Very unclear question.